Schema validation for producer using REST API does not validate schema [Apache Pulsar]
I'm having some issues with schema validation when using the REST API in Apache pulsar. When I use the python client, the data gets rejected if it does not adhere to the schema, (such as a required field missing). However, when I try the same using the same schema and the same topic using the REST API, the messages are accepted. To simplify, and reproduce the issue, I used the example provided here - https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/3.2.x/client-libraries-rest
 curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/topics/persistent/test/example/exampleTopic' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "valueSchema": "{\"name\":\"\",\"schema\":\"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\",\"type\":\"JSON\",\"properties\":{\"__jsr310ConversionEnabled\":\"false\",\"__alwaysAllowNull\":\"false\"},\"schemaDefinition\":\"{\\\"type\\\":\\\"record\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"PC\\\",\\\"namespace\\\":\\\"org.apache.pulsar.broker.admin.TopicsTest\\\",\\\"fields\\\":[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"brand\\\",\\\"type\\\":[\\\"null\\\",\\\"string\\\"],\\\"default\\\":null},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"gpu\\\",\\\"type\\\":[\\\"null\\\",{\\\"type\\\":\\\"enum\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"GPU\\\",\\\"symbols\\\":[\\\"AMD\\\",\\\"NVIDIA\\\"]}],\\\"default\\\":null},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"model\\\",\\\"type\\\":[\\\"null\\\",\\\"string\\\"],\\\"default\\\":null},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"seller\\\",\\\"type\\\":[\\\"null\\\",{\\\"type\\\":\\\"record\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"Seller\\\",\\\"fields\\\":[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"state\\\",\\\"type\\\":[\\\"null\\\",\\\"string\\\"],\\\"default\\\":null},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"street\\\",\\\"type\\\":[\\\"null\\\",\\\"string\\\"],\\\"default\\\":null},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"zipCode\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"long\\\"}]}],\\\"default\\\":null},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"year\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"int\\\"}]}\"}",
  "producerName": "rest-producer",
  "messages": [
    {
      "key":"my-key",
      "payload":"{\"brand\":\"dell\",\"model\":\"alienware\",\"year\":2021,\"gpu\":\"AMD\",\"seller\":{\"state\":\"WA\",\"street\":\"main street\",\"zipCode\":98004}}",
      "eventTime":1603045262772,
      "sequenceId":1
    },
    {
      "key":"my-key",
      "payload":"{\"brand\":\"asus\",\"model\":\"rog\",\"year\":2020,\"gpu\":\"NVIDIA\",\"seller\":{\"state\":\"CA\",\"street\":\"back street\",\"zipCode\":90232}}",
      "eventTime":1603045262772,
      "sequenceId":2
    },
    {
      "key":"my-key",
      "payload":"{}",
      "eventTime":1603045262772,
      "sequenceId":3
    }
  ]
}'


From the output, you can see that even an empty message gets accepted
{"messagePublishResults":[{"messageId":"55:21:-1","errorCode":0,"schemaVersion":0},{"messageId":"55:22:-1","errorCode":0,"schemaVersion":0},{"messageId":"55:23:-1","errorCode":0,"schemaVersion":0}],"schemaVersion":0}%

schema validation is enabled on the namespace, schema auto update is disabled and the schema update strategy was set to FORWARD. Is there anything I'm missing here, or is it not possible to do this using the rest api?
